# How can i create a "New" button on my VF page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am using custom object for my visualforce. How can i create a "New" button on my VF page so that it redirect me to the page where i can create my new record for that object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `{!URLFOR($Action.Custom_Object__c.New)}` to get the URL.